# What's the full sentence of "Where else" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “What a beautiful day it’s looking to be. You headed to the library?”

> “I am,” she answered. “Where else?”

I think the full sentence is:

> Where else would I go?

but I am not sure if I am right.

So could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is here:

> “Hey, Miss Wolcott,” the storekeeper said, pushing the few strands of
> hair he still had away from his florid face. “What a beautiful day
> it’s looking to be. You headed to the library?”
>
> “I am,” she answered. “**Where else**?”
>
> “I have some new red silk in. Tell your sisters. It
> would make a fine dress.”
>
> Elsa stopped. Red silk. She had never worn
> red silk.
>
> “Show me. Please.”

*The Four Winds* by Kristin Hannah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It essentially means:

> Where else would I be headed?

It's a rhetorical question that suggests that the person is *of course* going to the library, and sort of challenges the listener to name any other place to which it would be even remotely likely they were headed (of course, this isn't done in a serious way at all).

It's often used to express the way one feels about something. E.g., if the person were frustrated about having to go to the library to study, they would say this using quite a different tone than they would if they were excited to go to the library to research something.

**Example**

As a result of COVID-19, ones country may well be in “lockdown”, and one of the only places you can go is to the supermarket for household essentials. Your friend calls you on the phone:

You: Can I call you back? I’m literally just heading out.

Them: Ah, ok - to the supermarket?

You: Haha, yep! - where else?

The tone would likely be one of frustration and mild amusement.

**Example**

You’re talking to a friend, and it’s common knowledge that a mutual friend is throwing a party on Saturday.

You: Are you going out on Saturday?

Them: Yeah.

You: To the party?

Them: Where else?

This tone would likely be one of excitement and anticipation.

Comment: Could you give me please some more example of its usage?

Comment: Of course, I’ve added two examples to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The statement "I am." is given in response to the question "You headed to the library?". The second part of the response, "Where else?", is related to this question, and is completely understandable in context.

If the question were to be written out in full, it would be:

> "Where else would I be headed?"

Comment: Or "Where else would you expect me to be going?"